# In Libgdx sprite displaced from their bodies position just after colliding with another body

Tags: java, libgdx, sprites, box2d

In my game i have a ball falling from above and a rectangle below. when my rectangle collide with ball,sprite position displaced from body automatically,i could not understand this. and i also tried moving  Dynamic body using linear velocity it works fine but give problem after collision. here are picture before colliding and after colliding[image: before collision]

[image: After collision]

and my code is

```
  public class Ball extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
        SpriteBatch batch;
        Sprite sprite,sprite2;
        Texture img;
        Texture img1;
        World world;
        Body body,body2;
        Body ground;

        Matrix4 debugMatrix;
        OrthographicCamera camera;
        ExtendViewport viewport;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;

        float SCALE=0.05f;


        @Override
        public void create (){
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            img = new Texture("ball.png");
            img1=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
            camera=new OrthographicCamera();
            viewport= new ExtendViewport(50,50,camera);


            sprite = new Sprite(img);
            sprite2 = new Sprite(img1);
            sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth()*SCALE,sprite.getHeight()*SCALE);
            sprite2.setSize(sprite2.getWidth()*SCALE,sprite2.getHeight()*SCALE);

            world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10f),true);
             createBall();
            createRect();
            debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {
            viewport.update(width, height, true);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            createGround();
        }

        private void createBall(){
            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
            bodyDef.position.set(MathUtils.random(15,30),50);
             CircleShape circleShape=new CircleShape();
            circleShape.setRadius(1.2f);
            body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
            FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
            fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
            fixtureDef.density = 0.1f;
            fixtureDef.restitution = 0.2f;
            fixtureDef.friction=0.2f;
            body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
            circleShape.dispose();
        }

        private void createRect(){
            BodyDef bodyDef2 = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef2.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
            bodyDef2.position.set(25,10);
            body2 = world.createBody(bodyDef2);
            FixtureDef fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();
            PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
            shape.setAsBox(sprite2.getWidth()/2, sprite2.getHeight()/2);
            fixtureDef2.shape = shape;
            fixtureDef2.density = 0.1f;
            fixtureDef2.restitution = 0.7f;
            fixtureDef2.friction=0.2f;
            body2.createFixture(fixtureDef2);
            shape.dispose();
        }


            private void createGround() {

                BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
                bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
                FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
                PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
                shape.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 1);
                fixtureDef.shape = shape;
                ground = world.createBody(bodyDef);
                ground.createFixture(fixtureDef);
                ground.setTransform(0, 0, 0);

                shape.dispose();


            }
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            img.dispose();
            world.dispose();
        }




        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2);
            sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x-sprite.getWidth()/2,
                    body.getPosition().y-sprite.getHeight()/2 );

            sprite.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(body2.getAngle()));
            sprite2.setPosition(body2.getPosition().x - sprite2.getWidth()/2,
                    body2.getPosition().y -sprite2.getHeight()/2 );
            sprite2.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));


            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(sprite, sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(),sprite.getOriginX(),
                    sprite.getOriginY(),
                    sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight(),sprite.getScaleX(),sprite.
                            getScaleY(),sprite.getRotation());
            batch.draw(sprite2, sprite2.getX(), sprite2.getY(),sprite2.getOriginX(),
                    sprite2.getOriginY(),
                    sprite2.getWidth(),sprite2.getHeight(),sprite2.getScaleX(),sprite2.
                        getScaleY(),sprite2.getRotation());
            batch.end();
            debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            if(keycode== Input.Keys.LEFT)        //get some linear velocity
                body2.setLinearVelocity(-10f,0);
            if(keycode==Input.Keys.RIGHT)
                body2.setLinearVelocity(10f,5);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            if(keycode== Input.Keys.LEFT)   
                body2.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
            if(keycode==Input.Keys.RIGHT)
                body2.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally got this problem solved by just adding this line of code to the bodies

```
body.setFixedRotation=true;
```